# getOpenSessions() giving empty [ ] value

Tags: java, session, websocket

I am trying save the sessions in Set  allSession , but the getOpenSessions() method creating an empty array. My code looks like -

```
@OnOpen
public void onOpen(Session session){
    System.out.println(session.getId() + " has opened a connection");
    System.out.println(" Session: "+session.getOpenSessions());
    try {
        session.getBasicRemote().sendText("Connection Established");
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

So, It's giving me an result -

1 has opened a connection

Session []

Can anyone suggest what is the exact problem here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for the delayed answer. The bug was tomcat version 8.0. Tomcat 7 is more stable. I am using this from 3,4 months but session related issue is coming. Hope this information will help you.

Answer (score 0):

i got the same problem...but when i used the method in the @onMessage annotation method ..it works fine...the set is showing the elements...

Answer (score 0):

this worked!

```
    @OnMessage
    public String echo(String msg) throws IOException {
   
        Set<Session> set1 =  wsSession.getOpenSessions();
        
        System.out.println("set:  "+set1);
        
         Iterator<Session> iter = set1.iterator();
         
         while(iter.hasNext()) {
             
             
               System.out.println("entered inside while");
               
         }
    }
```